# Why do native speakers sometimes use “dispel with something” instead of using "dispel something"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

*Dispel* is defined as a transitive verb in dictionaries. But I notice native speakers sometimes use "dispel **with** something" instead of using "dispel something".

I just came across this sentence said by presidential candidate Sen.Marco Rubio,

> Let’s dispel **with** this fiction that Barack Obama doesn’t know what he’s doing. He knows exactly what he’s doing.

I've also googled and got some other examples,

> Let's please dispel **with** the notion that opposing women in direct combat and conscription is sexist.
>
> What myths are you trying to dispel **with** this book and who is the audience?

I consulted dictionaries but didn't find any examples of such usage with a preposition "**with**". Then why do native speakers sometimes use “dispel with something” instead of using "dispel something"? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Read [**The Other Problem With Marco Rubio’s Broken Record: “Dispel With” Isn’t a Thing.**](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2016/02/07/marco_rubio_broken_record_in_republican_debate_is_grammatically_incorrect.html) Seems it was a rather unique usage.

Comment: I just googled and found some sentences like "What myths are you trying to dispel with this book and who is the audience?"

Comment: Well maybe "incorrect" would have been more accurate than "unique". But even in this example, "disprove" would have been better.

Comment: We can use the phrasal verb  dispense with instead of dispel with as dispel needs no preposition.

Comment: CBN news: Let's please dispel with the notion that opposing women in direct combat and conscription is sexist.

Answer (score 7):

In the first two sentences, the speaker is using the wrong word: 'dispel' when the correct word is 'dispense'.  This kind of error is common enough in English that we have a word for it: [Malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism)

> Let’s dispense with this fiction that Barack Obama doesn’t know what
>   he’s doing.

In the third sentence, the verb 'to dispel' applies to the myths, not the book.  'with this book' is a separate clause.

> What myths are you trying to dispel?
>
> I'm trying to dispel myths about dating.

Adding the clause back in:

> What myths are you trying to dispel with this book?
>
> I'm trying to dispel myths about dating with this book.

Comment: A minor correction "with this book" is a phrase, not a clause, I think, since there is nothing actively "verbing" in it.

Answer (score 3):

Native speakers normally don't. To many people, this sounded like an error. In cases of preposition use like this, there is no clear line between "grammatical error" and "usage error," but "dispel with something" is definitely not a usual turn of phrase. The linguist Mark Liberman made a post about it on Language Log ([Badly scripted](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=23968)) where he discusses other possible examples of this construction. His conclusion:

> Given the sparseness of this construction, I'm inclined to continue to regard it as a sporadic malaprop.